# Filling a hole made in a wood stud

Tags: structural, load-bearing, structure

Bottomline, I think I've made a huge mistake.

I was drilling through studs in a load bearing wall to pass a cable. This is on a doubled-up stud going perpendicular into a joist. Definitely load bearing.

There was not a whole lot of space to position my drill perpendicularly and in my frustration trying to get this done I foolishly angled the drill bit to make the hole. (I really wasn't thinking and what I had done dawned on me afterwards)

My fear is that I got really close to the edge of the second stud as my drill bit was so angled and that this could be potentially unsafe.

Is there any thing I can fill the hole with like Liquid Nails which will harden and return the studs to good?

[image]

Edit: Note the drawing is not to scale, It's a 3/8 hole - it doesn't look that bad in person. I tend to be paranoid about these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to fill the hole and filling it would not make much improvement.  If you have access to the side of the stud that the hole goes too close too, you could use a special nail on reinforcement plate to reinforce the edge of the stud. Even if this is a load bearing wall the construction requirements have a large safety factor.

To pass electrical inspection you might have to drill another hole above or below where you have it right now so the wire will be in the middle of the stud. This is not so much for strength but to reduce the chances that later putting a nail or screw into or near the stud would penetrate the wire.

**EDIT**

The framing experts on this site might say that it would be better to redrill the hole in the same spot, but this time perpendicular, then nail a reinforcing plate over the original hole that was too close to the edge.

Comment: Absolutely use nail plates. (Not for strength, just to prevent future piercing.)

Comment: I agree. You can take out half a stud and it doesn't dramatically affect the wall as a system. Re-drill wherever you like.

Comment: I was suggesting using a nailing plate on the 3.5" face of the 2 x 4 over the hole that was too close to the edge, or maybe a length of 2 x2 or ripped 2x4 sistered on there. I certainly hope he is using nailing plates on the edges of any studs where the wiring goes through. I am at the stage of life where I am installing grab bars all over in our house and for some elderly neighbors. I wish nailing plates had been used on our houses when they were built in 1969-70 but they weren't.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what loads the stud carry and the spacing. by code you can notch out 25% of a structural member or drill a hole in the center 40% for a bearing wall and 60% for non load bearing. But to be safe you can add  a plywood plate to the edge of the studs and put in about 15 wood screws. This will help carry bending and compression loads.

Inspector Jeff

ICC/FL/SC licensed combination building inspector and building designer